# Development workflow with Jenkins + Git + Crucible + Jira?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jira, atlassian-crucible

Developer team has specific requirements for tools. [[I have]](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/generated-jenkins-jobs-and-automatic-branch-merging-for-feature-branches/) [[read]](http://www.sitepoint.com/supercharge-continuous-delivery-jenkins-workflow-plugin/) [[a lot]](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/) [[about]](http://blogs.atlassian.com/tag/jenkins/) [[ideal]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McTZtyb9M38) [[workflows]](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) and came up with something that works like this:

1. Developer creates a change request, hotfix, feature, etc in **Jira**. That unique item id will be tracked along the work flow.
2. Developer pulls repo from **Git**, creates a `feature-a` branch, commit changes locally and pushes to remote git repo. **Pushes to `master` are forbidden.**
3. Git hook triggers a **Jenkins** job which runs a smoke test (compilation and unit tests). If tests pass then creates a revision in **Crucible**.
4. Unless code review committee approves changes, we have to start from step (1). **Crucible** triggers a **Jenkins** job.
5. **Jenkins** auto merges to `master`. If it fails then a manual merge is required and go back to step (2). Review step (4) might be bypassed.
6. **Jenkins** starts QA tests (integration tests, static analysis, system tests, IP scan, etc.).
7. **Gatekeeper** (or senior developer) promotes that particular commit for release candidate.

Jenkins has a lot of plugins but nothing that works out-of-the-box. I need to develop many connectors (Jenkins-Crucible, Jenkins-Git for auto-merge). Changing tools is not an option.

**How can I simplify the workflow?**

Comment: did you think about a pull requests in **Stash** instead of using **Crucible**?

Comment: I'd recommend running your tests before merging the changes into master (Step 6).  Ideally, master should be shippable at any time.  I'd also re-think the gatekeeper - they can become a bottleneck